# How to broad cast message or fire any event from web apps to win apps

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, notifications, signalr

suppose i have one web site from where job applicant post their CV along with other data. i have another win form apps which is invoke by win scheduler periodically. when win form apps run then download job applicant data  along with their CV to local file and database system. our win form apps works perfectly. our company want me to develop win apps in such a way when anyone upload their CV along with other data then a notification come from our website to our win apps and then our win apps download that new CV with other data locally.

this job can be developed few ways.
1) i can use .Net sql server dependency related class to notify our win apps when any new data inserted or modified.

2) i am not familiar with signalr but heard that singalr can send notification from web apps to win form client. i just like to know is it true ??
if yes then any one can guide me how singalr can send notification to my win apps. also tell me what i need to do at the end of win form. need guidance who is familiar with signalr.

3) also guide me how i can use WCF here to send notification from our web site to win form apps.

so please guide me what will be best way to handle this situation and also discuss all my three points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick guide for signalR: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

Answer (score 0):

yes in this instant i recommend the use of signalR check the pluralsight.com website they have a course about signalR http://www.pluralsight.com